# VB.NET Winforms menu item shortcuts overriding default shortcuts?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, keyboard-shortcuts

In a VB.NET Winforms application, I have a form that contains both a datagridview and a textbox.  I have some menu item entries that have shortcuts of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> that operate on the datagridview.  However, these override the default cut, copy, and paste shortcuts for the textbox.  How can I make the menu shortcuts only apply when the datagridview has focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper UI design requires disabling the menu item when it isn't functional.  A side-effect is that it will no longer steal the keystroke, just what you want.  The Application.Idle event is handy for that.

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        AddHandler Application.Idle, Application_Idle
    End Sub
    Private Sub Application_Idle(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        CopyToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = DataGridView1.Focus
        '' etc...
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `DataGridView.GotFocus` event, assign the shortcuts and in the `LostFocus` event remove them again.

So something like this:

```
Private Sub DataGridView_GotFocus(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles DataGridView.GotFocus
  menuItem1.Shortcut = Shortcut.CtrlV
End sub

Private Sub DataGridView_LostFocus(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles DataGridView.LostFocus
  menuItem1.Shortcut = Shortcut.None
End sub
```

Generally though, I would not assign other functions to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> keys.